# Bootstrap 4 Fields not lining up correctly in form group inline

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 on a few pages and i am having issues trying to lineup the fields with labels to the left and ensuring the input fields appear aligned.

Here is my code

```
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
 <div id="formContent">
    <!-- Tabs Titles -->
    <div id="formHeader">
        <a class="underlineHover" href="/">Login</a>
        <a class="underlineHover" >Register</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Icon -->

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <form th:action="@{/register}" method="post">

        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="playerName"> Player Name</label>
            <input type="text" required="true" id="playerName" autofocus="autofocus " class="fadeIn second form-control" name="playerName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="playerId"> Username</label>
            <input type="text" required="true" autofocus="autofocus " class="fadeIn second form-control" id="playerId" name="playerId"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="email"> Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" required="true" autofocus="autofocus " class="fadeIn second form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@email.com"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="password"> Password</label>
            <input type="password" required="true" id="password" class="fadeIn third form-control" name="password" data-toggle="password"/>
            <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                 <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
             </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="password"> League Code</label>
            <input type="text" id="league" class="fadeIn third form-control" name="leagueCode"/>
        </div>

        <div th:if="${failure}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <p th:text="${failure}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Register">
    </form>

    <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
    <div id="formFooter">
        <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I have tried using individual rows for each one but that is not working either.

Here is what the page looks like:

[image: mis-aligned fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u expecting like this :

```css
#registration-btn{
width:90px;
outline:none;
border:none;
line-height:40px;
color:white;
background-color:#23b2e2;
border-radius:10px;
}
.form-inline .form-control{
width:80% !important;
}
#formContent{
text-align:center;
}
.input_box{
width:75%;
display:flex;
}
.input-group-text{
padding:0.8%;
}
label{
width:25%;
}
.form-group{
display:flex;
}
.form-control{
width:100%;
}
#password{
 width:calc(80% - 40px) !important;
}
.password-eye{
width: 40px;
text-align: center;
 border-radius: 4px;
background-color: lightgrey;
line-height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
   <div id="formContent">
      <div id="formHeader">
         <a class="underlineHover" href="/">Login</a>
         <a class="underlineHover" >Register</a>
      </div>
      <form th:action="@{/register}" method="post">
         <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="playerName"> Player Name</label>
            <div class="input_box">
               <input type="text" required="true" id="playerName" autofocus="autofocus " class="fadeIn second form-control" name="playerName"/>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="playerId"> Username</label>
            <div class="input_box">
               <input type="text" required="true" autofocus="autofocus " class="fadeIn second form-control" id="playerId" name="playerId"/>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="email"> Email Address</label>
            <div class="input_box">
               <input type="text" required="true" autofocus="autofocus " class="fadeIn second form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@email.com"/>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="password"> Password</label>
            <div class="input_box">      
               <input type="password" required="true" id="password" class="fadeIn third form-control" name="password" data-toggle="password"/>
            <span class="password-eye">
                  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                  </span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <label for="password"> League Code</label>
            <div class="input_box">
               <input type="text" id="league" class="fadeIn third form-control" name="leagueCode"/>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <input type="submit" id="registration-btn" class="fadeIn fourth" value="REGISTER" >
         </div>
         <div>
            <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that is almost correct, but the password field doesn't line up correctly.  Also the Register button is much bigger like a square and the word "register" appears over on the right hand side.  I will try and play around with this and see.  Is it possible to upload images to comments?

Comment: See the image here the registration and email are not correct and the line break that was there previously below the login/register link and above the Forgot Password link(text).  https://imge.to/i/fzCTq

Comment: Fiddled around with your suggestions and it works now thanks @Amaresh S M :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, using `form-group row` would help instead of `form-group form-inline`.

Look at the example: (Please open in full page view for actual size)

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Radios</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios1" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">
            First radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios2" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios2">
            Second radio
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check disabled">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gridRadios" id="gridRadios3" value="option3" disabled>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios3">
            Third disabled radio
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
          Example checkbox
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So that works for the first two fields, but then goes awry.   For example the email resizes bigger, the appended password(image) appears on a new line and when you click the eye icon it doesn't do anything .